# Razor templates not found

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I am trying out ASP.NET Core RC2 for the first time.  I managed to get routing to my controller working -- if the controller returns `Content("hello world")`, I see the string "hello world" returned to my browser.

If the controller returns `View()` though, I get an error that

> The View 'Index' was not found.  The following locations were searched: /Views/Controller/Index.cshtml ...

I confirmed the view is in the right place in the folder structure, following the typical convention. I know how to make this work in other versions of ASP.NET.

It's my first time using ASP.NET Core, though, and I'm trying to configure it all by hand, so I wonder what I'm missing - maybe I need something to register Razor in the pipeline, or to register the search path for the templates?

In my `project.json` I have dependencies for both `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor`.

Comment: Did you scaffold the new project with Visual Studio, or some other way?

Comment: No, trying to do it all by hand - the presence of command-line tools seems like it should make VS less critical

Comment: Do you have `var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath) [...]` in your `Startup` method?

Comment: No - and it looked like I needed to add `UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` to my Program.cs as well.  If you make that an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working `Program.cs` file for ASP.NET Core RC2 looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

If ASP.NET Core is complaining about not being able to find files, make sure that `UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` is present. This will set the "base" path that Razor uses to search for views.